# Como verificar se um valor está contido em outra lista

Tags: r

Eu preciso conferir se o valor de uma coluna está contido em uma lista e, se estiver, copio o seu o valor para uma terceira coluna.

Vamos o exemplo:

```
df <- data.frame(Nome = c("Maria", "Pedro", "João","Mário"),
       Situação = c("regular","irregular","regular","Isento"),
       valor = c(1,2,1,5),
       resultado = c(0,0,0,0))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
lista <- list(c("regular","Isento"))
```

Agora preciso conferir se o valor (linha a linha) da coluna Situação está contida na lista e trazer o resultado na linha correspondente da coluna resultado

Pensei em fazer com `for`:

```
for (i in seq(nrow(df))) {
  if (**???**) {
    df[i,4] <- Base[i,3]
  }
}
```

e o resultado seria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu escrevo essa condição no `if` para que o R verifique se o valor está contido na lista?

Answer (score 6):

Pode-se fazer o que a pergunta pede com um índice lógico criado com `%in%`.

```
i <- df$Situação %in% unlist(lista)
df$resultado <- 0
df$resultado[i] <- df$valor[i]

df
#   Nome  Situação valor resultado
#1 Maria   regular     1         1
#2 Pedro irregular     2         0
#3  João   regular     1         1
#4 Mário    Isento     5         5
```